# Prove that $N \subseteq H$

Tags: group-theory

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and let $\pi∶G \rightarrow G/N$ be the homomorphism $\pi(a) = aN.$
Suppose $K$ is a subgroup of $G/N.$ In a previous exercise we showed that
$H = \{g ∈ G ∶ \pi(g) \in K\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

So take an element in $N$ and show that element is in $H$? What does an element in $N$ look like? I know its a normal subgroup of $G$ so can I say an element looks like $gng^{-1}$ for $n \in N$? If so, where do I go from there how do I tie all this together. I can try to work backwards and see what an element in $H$ looks like and try to meet in the middle. Would an element in $H$ look like $gN?$ And that is a left coset so it would looks like $g^{-1}n$ for $n \in N?$ Am I completely off? Yeh I need some help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a\in N$; $aN=N$ since $N$ is a subgroup. Since $K\le G/N$, $K$ must contain the identity of $G/N$, which is just $N$. By definition, then, $a\in H$, and since $a$ is arbitrary we get $N\subseteq H$.

Comment: @PhysicsBish Since $a\in N$, multiplying it by any element in $N$ gives another element in $N$ ($N$, being a group, is closed under the group operation).

Comment: Did you mean $a \in K$ or $a \in G$ at the end?

Comment: @PhysicsBish $a\in H$ is correct... $\pi(a)\in K$.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I am catching you in the middle of some of your edits on your answer so I got confused haha.

Answer (score 1):

The elements of $G/N$ are of the form $gN$ for $g\in G$, and the identity element of $G/N$ is $N$.

Easy way to do it: notice that $H=\pi^{-1}(K)$ and that $N=\pi^{-1}(\{N\})$ and that $\{N\}\subset K$.

If you want to do it more by "hands", take an element $n\in N$. To show that $n\in H$, you must show that $\pi(n)\in K$. But $\pi(n)=nN=N$.

Answer (score 1):

To show $N \subseteq H$ all you have to do is verify that is satisfies the definition provided for $H$.
Writing $A \subseteq B$ is basically shorthand for writing $x \in A \implies x\in B$. So you have to show:
$x\in N \implies \pi (x) \in K$.

There’s no need to know “what elements in N look like”, since you actually don’t know... because you aren’t given any additional hypothesis.